# CSS Responsive grid 1px gap issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, grid-layout

I am working on a responsive grid system for a project. The grid is made up of blocks which are floated left and have a **width** of **25%**.

Inside these block are are images which are set to either **100%** **height/width** or **50%** **height/width**.

All the images within the blocks a butted up next to each other, and all the blocks are butted up next to each other so it looks like a seamless grid of images.

The issue I'm getting is at certain browser sizes or when you resize the browser you get a little 1px gap between certain blocks.

An example can be seen here:
http://dahliacreative.com/responsivegrid/

I think it may be down to the blocks floating as if you take the float off all seems fine.
I tried using `display: inline-block` etc, but couldn't get anything working!

Does anyone have an idea to fix this ?

Answer (score 3):

This is due to using full round percentages such as 50%, when you get to certain widths and heights (e.g 561px * 393px) then those won't divide into 50% evenly hence this remaining 1px gap.

Have a look at twitter bootstrap CSS to see the percentages done to 6 decimal points to avoid this issue.

Comment: so will one side have to be bigger than the other?

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by adding css class to last column, css for this class

```
.your_class_for_last_column { float: left !important;} 
/* TO FIX 1px Foundation 5 bug fix*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new css3 with colum gap and column count.

```
column-count:
column-gap:
```

Chris made a really good example with images, which is related to yours.
You can do almost the same thing with li or table or so on elements
Make sure to use prefix and doesn't work in IE less than 10

http://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/